# jQuery change text of all next elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, jquery-selectors

I would like to get all next specific class Elements and change the text of them. Specifically the number of the entry because i've made an ajax request to delete a record in a datatabse and i don't want to reload the page.

First i get the actual entry number to know which text (or entry Number) should be replaced (for loop)

```
$entryHeadContent = $this.closest('.entry').find('.entry-head').text();
$entryID = parseInt($entryHeadContent.split('|')[0].replace(/ /g,''));
```

Then i would like to go through all next entry-heads to change the actual entry number (decrease the number by 1).

```
alert($this.nextAll('.entry-head').length); // Is 0

$this.nextAll('.entry-head').each(function(index){
    alert($this.nextAll('.entry-head').length);
    for (i = entryID; i <= $this.nextAll('.entry-head').length; i++) { 
        index.text().replace(i, (i -1)) 
        alert('Index: ' + index + ' | ');
    }
});
```

But somehow that code don't seems to be executed but i don't get it. Why? $this is the form (test). I'm still in the ajax request (in the .done part of the ajax request.

This is the entry html(tpl) file, for one entry:

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="entry-head">
        #{$entryNumber} | 
        Name: {$entry.name}
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="entry-content">
        {$entry.message}
        <form action="index.php?site=entry" class="test" method="post">
            <div class="entry-options">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');" name="delete">

                 <input type="hidden" value="{$entry.id}" name="entryID">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have `$this.nextAll('.entry-head').each(function(index){` in `$(document.ready())` right?

Comment: Sounds like it could be done in CSS only, see e.g: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/

Comment: yeah, it's in $(document.ready())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
$this.nextAll('.entry-head').each(function(index){
    alert($this.nextAll('.entry-head').length);
    for (i = entryID; i <= $this.nextAll('.entry-head').length; i++) { 
        index.text().replace(i, (i -1)) 
        alert('Index: ' + index + ' | ');
    }
});
```

Doesn't it seem weird to you that you do `index.text();` . Seeing that index is just a number and not a jquery object. .each() also comes with a second parameter in the callback. `function(index, value){}`

```
$this.nextAll('.entry-head').each(function(index, value){
    alert($this.nextAll('.entry-head').length);
    for (i = entryID; i <= $this.nextAll('.entry-head').length; i++) { 
        $(value).text().replace(i, (i -1)) 
        alert('Actual Index: ' + index + ' | ');
    }
});
```

I would think this would work better?

**Update:**

I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eg8uh2zc/2/) partially working. Before I continue, tell me if I'm on the same wavelength as you.

**Update:**

Bugged --> [demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/eg8uh2zc/6/)

Fixed --> [Demo3](https://jsfiddle.net/eg8uh2zc/7/)

```
   $('.test').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $this2 = $this.closest('.entry').find('.entry-head');
    var $entryID = parseInt($this2.text().split('|')[0].replace(/ /g,''));
    alert($entryID);
    var $entries = $('.entry-head').not($this2).filter(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).text().split('|')[0].replace(/ /g, '')) > $entryID;
    }); // Is 0

    $entries.each(function (index, value) {
            var id = $entryID + index + 1;
            $(value).text($(value).text().replace(id, (id-1)));
            console.log('Index: ' + index + ' | ' + $entryID);
    });
});
```

Comment: nothing seems "weird" when you're learning how to program, +1 on the answer though

Comment: yeah, a small misstake, thanks for that hint but that code is still not being executed because nothing is changing and i don't get any error.

Comment: I see you added that $this.nextAll('.entry-head').length returns 0. Can you add to your post what your $this is? @Procos, thanks.

Comment: this is the form. You can see it above in my post. It's the class "test"

Comment: @Procos I'm working on your problem. I see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Procos I have a partial solution. Before I continue let me know if this what you were expecting.

Comment: Prett much yes, but it's just one entry. For each entry i make the entry html file, so it's like this: https://jsfiddle.net/eg8uh2zc/4/. Err .. missed to change the entryID but i hope you know what i mean. All of the entrys are also in a container called entrys.

Comment: @Procos actually there is a minor bug.. fixing it

Comment: Yeah, now it's right. Like i said there is also a container (id entrys) arround all the entry(s). If i click at the delete 1 button now 2 is getting 1 and 3 is getting 2, that's right. But it actaully does only work for the first entry in your fiddle.

Comment: Yep, that's what i wanted to do. I've also found my bug now but i also tried to do it with closest but it didn't work, dunno why .. Thanks for your help, now it's working all correctly! ;)